# Calendar with high value on privacy

Tags: calendar, privacy

I'm looking for a set of calendar apps from providers that highly value privacy. Something like Google is therefore out of question. At the moment I am using an app on my phone, that I can only access locally. I would like it to thave the following features:

- Be able to plan on the computer e.g. Webinterface
- Access and edit your calendar from phone
- Manage TODO
- See birthdays
- Not subscription based or at least low price if it is, I would pay a rather high price up front though

Edit: Operating systems: Windows / Android

Comment: If self-hosting is an option: I use my own Nextcloud (on the PC: web interface), syncing it to my Androids via DAVx, and can use any calendar app on Android (e.g. Etar – or any other one from F-Droid). If you cannot self-host, there are several trustworthy providers out there hosting it for you, for a small fee. Some even include mail (like mailbox.org) and more.

Answer (score 2):

You may check out [Proton's calendar app](https://proton.me/calendar).

They have a [free tier](https://proton.me/pricing?product=calendar) (which also gives you mail, VPN and cloud storage) and provide web access and mobile apps.

Answer (score 1):

If between Windows Desktop and your Android phone, a suggestion is to use:

- The default calendar that comes on Android, but partner it with the [MyPhoneExplorer](https://www.fjsoft.at/en/) app. It can sync between your Android phone and its own desktop app. It can even sync with your desktop MS Outlook, if you choose to.
- As a bonus, it can also sync notes, contacts, sms, files with your desktop.
- The calendar on the desktop can manage birthdays (via contact field), tasks, etc
- Syncing can be done using USB cable, or WIFI/Bluetooth (if you trust the wireless connection).
- Remove or disable google account on the phone, so that no syncing with Google.
- It is a free app, but you can make a donation to the author.

This is a configuration I have been using for a long time. But you may well get other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Besides ProtonMail (Sebastian's recommendation) there is also a calendar from [Tutanota](https://tutanota.com/calendar/) and (still relatively new) [Peergos](https://peergos.org/posts/calendar).